# Virtual Box - USB Mounting & Formatting Issue

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox

I am trying to create a startup disk on a USB. I attempted to use the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator but that failed. I then turned to UNetBootin. That seemingly worked but I still wasn't able to boot from it. Now the USB will not mount to any of my VMs (all linux). I attempted to reformat the usb on my host (Windows) and that didn't work.

Virtual Box is still recognizing the drive but the Linux OS isn't mounting it. And the Windows reformat keeps failing. Any ideas?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: without error message and output hard to help you.

Comment: the message was just that the format failed on the windows host. but on the VM it just stopped mounting.

Answer (score 0):

- For the formatting issue on Windows:

You can try to open a command prompt typing `cmd` in the Run dialog box.
Then for example `format E: /fs:FAT` where E: is your USB stick drive letter and FAT is the filesystem you want to use.

Comment: I have since passed the USB onto a more experience person. I will let you know what he uses to resolve the issue. I will suggest this method.

Answer (score 0):

Use DBAN (Dariks Boot And Nuke) to completely wipe the device and then use http://rufus.akeo.ie/ to help create the bootable USB.

Hope this helps :)